# Laravel 10 Centos 7 htaccess file deleted but still loading

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, laravel-10

I managed to get my websites fully deployed on digital ocean running apache except after I added the ssl cert,  it failed to start. Upon looking into the error log, this is what I received.

```
[Tue Mar 14 05:33:19.296072 2023] [core:alert] [pid 19204] [client 183.129.153.157:51241] /home/centos/www/mysite/public/.htaccess: /home/centos/www/mysite/public/.htaccess:1: <<<<<<<> was not closed.
```

That htaccess file was deleted and I released that project on its own server. The virtual host file associated with it was also deleted.

Update: Turns out I had forgotten to run "setenforce 0"
but I have a new error
httpd: Syntax error on line 356 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Could not open config directory /home/centos/vhosts: Permission denied

the directory and all subfolders have 755 permissions

my virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin me@me.com
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot "/home/centos/www/mysite/public"
        ErrorLog /home/centos/logs/error_log
        CustomLog /home/centos/logs/access_log combined
        <Directory "/home/centos/www/casacoding/public">
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride All
                        Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin me@me.com
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot "/home/centos/www/mysite/public"
        ErrorLog /home/centos/logs/error_log
        CustomLog /home/centos/logs/access_log combined
        <Directory "/home/centos/www/mysite/public">
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride All
                        Require all granted
        </Directory>
        SSLCertificateFile "/home/centos/vhosts/mysite-com.csr"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/centos/vhosts/mysite-com.key"
        SSLCertificateChainFile "/home/centos/vhosts/sslcert/CER - CRT Files/STAR_casacoding_com.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: also when I run configtest it returns syntaxOK\

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!!
the private key had the right permissions but was in the centos group instead of the root group. bam! working!